# Looking for book/notes about designing rotatry indexer cam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I'm looking for a book/notes about designing a rotary indexer like in this video (the first system until 34 sec):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2atiOFA-qnQ

For example, I need table= top plate with 5 stations/stops. The rotating cam driving angle is 240 deg, and in the rest 120 deg the table isn't turning.

Comment: I'm not an engineer, but it seems to me that the cam could be designed in a linear form, and then wrapped into a cylinder

Comment: have you considered some version of a geneva gear instead of a cam?

Comment: Ithought about geneva mechanis. Compering to the rotary indexer, its larger is total size. And the axes of of the indexer ar not parallel, which is an advantage for me.